# Flutter - Camera permission pop up not closing after deny

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am using this QR Code Scanner plugin `https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner` in my flutter app. For this my app is requesting for camera permission, If I deny the camera permission, the pop is not closing, it is appearing again and again.

Below is my android manifest.xml permission code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Below is my code for scanning the QR using this plugin

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return QRView(
          key: qrKey,
          onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
          overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
            borderColor: AppColors.APP_PRIMARY_COLOR,
            borderRadius: AppSizeConstants.size10,
            borderLength: AppSizeConstants.size30,
            borderWidth: AppSizeConstants.size10,
            cutOutSize: 300.0,
          ),
          onPermissionSet: (ctrl, permission) async =>
              await _onPermissionSet(context, ctrl, permission),
        );
  }

void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        String QRCodeValue = result?.code.toString() ?? "";
        print("Scanned Data is:$QRCodeValue");
        controller.pauseCamera();
      });
    });
  }

  _onPermissionSet(
    BuildContext context,
    QRViewController ctrl,
    bool permissionGranted,
  ) async {
    if (!permissionGranted) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      await controller?.resumeCamera();
    }
  }
```

If I allow the permission for camera, the pop up is closing properly and working as expected, suppose, **If I deny the permission, that same permission pop up is appearing again and again, it's not closing**.

Can someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you try some thing else than  Navigator.pop(context); in !permissionGranted

Comment: @Dev Yeah I Did, I tried to dispose the controller, still the same.